# Table Stacking and Resizing with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, scaling

I am trying to build a fairly simple email using HTML and CSS where it can either by 300px wide or 600px wide depending on the following @media:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) { /* Mobiles etc */ }
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { /* Tablets or Desktops etc */ }
```

I then have a table with two tables within it, which stack as soon as I resize the browser to less than 600px, which is fine.  I have done this by:

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {  
  .floatLeftResponse{
    width:100% !important;
    float:left;
  }
```

However, I can't seem to get everything working properly because my entire email is either made up of one table 600px wide or the same with two 50% tables within it.  In some scenarios I want the right side to go on top of the left and vice versa.

Then we have the images which are 600px wide, which should also scale down to 300px wide.

Since I am fairly new to all this I have been doing a lot of Googling, and every time I get one part working I somehow manage to break the other parts.  Any help would be appreciated guys :)

Comment: FYI, a lot of email clients [do not support media queries](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/)

Comment: @jlego, what should I use then to make my emails "responsive"?

Comment: You can utilize media queries for the ones that do support it, as long as you are aware that they aren't as cross-client supported as they are in web browsers. Litmus, Campaign Monitor, and MailChimp all have articles and resources on best practices for this.

Comment: Do your tables have borders on them? Can you set up a JSFiddle perhaps?

Comment: @jlego, my tables do not have any borders.  Hadn't heard of JSFiddle before but will have a play tonight.  I would want it to switch to 300px wide on smaller devices like a mobile (Android/Apple) and the normal 600px wide on tablets/PCs... what would do this if not @media?

Comment: @media is the correct answer. I was just presenting the information in case you were not aware and were testing in a client that does not support them.

Comment: @jlego, I have started with this: http://jsfiddle.net/hirenshah/k7wg3yry/4/    Seems to be working in Chrome but messes up in IE9 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out by building the entire email from scratch based on what I know rather than using online guides:
http://jsfiddle.net/hirenshah/k7wg3yry/4/

```
<body bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Header Table Start -->
            <table dir="rtl" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="35%" dir="ltr" class="table">RIGHT HAND SIDE LOGO</td>
                    <td width="65%" dir="ltr" class="table">Quote Number: 1234567890</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Header Table End -->
            <!-- Image Banner Table Start -->
            <table class="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://effervescence.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/UnencumberedSharingCircleBanner600px.jpg" class="resize" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Image Banner Table End -->
            <!-- Intro Text Start -->
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dear Mr Smith,
                        <br>We are a recognized leader in enterprise engagement and customer experience management and today are proud to count some of the world's largest brands as our customers.
                        <br>
                        <br>The inspiration for our company name is the Thunderhead cloud - a type of storm cloud that signals disruption and turbulence. It's symbolic of the change we bring to enterprise software; a cloud based solution provider leading from the front to revolutionize customer engagement and design-led ease of use.
                        <br>
                        <br>Since launching in 2004, we have become an acknowledged leader in our market, with operations in three continents, and a client base that includes some of the best known companies in the financial services and investment banking world.
                        <br>
                        <br>We help our customers succeed by providing them with innovative technology solutions that enable them to more effectively communicate, collaborate and engage with their customers, employees and partners.
                            </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Intro Text End -->
            <!-- Header Table Start -->
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" class="table">
                        <p>You have bought stuff</p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%" class="table">
                        <p>But you can also buy this stuff</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Header Table End -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    /* Mobile Devices */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .table {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }
    .container {
        width:300px;
        !important max-width:300px;
        !important
    }
    img.resize {
        max-width:300px;
        height:auto;
    }
}
/* All Other Devices */
 .container {
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width:600px;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
}
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.left {
    text-align: left;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```